# Where to download WSDL definitions with external schema location

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

I'm not particularly well-versed in the area of web services, but I'm trying to test an application constructed in Java, designed to manage web service requests(something like SPAOUI).

My approach involves utilizing pre-existing custom WSDL definition files and attempting to import them into the application. However, an error is encountered when the application relies on an external schema (.xsd file).

I am trying to find WSDL definition samples with SchemaLocation, and I am unable to locate any functional examples.

Could someone help me with sample WSDL definitions containing external schemas?

I found below wsdl definition example from github
https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf/blob/master/src/test/resources/wsdl/BankCustomerService.wsdl

But its references to Schema Location with Relative path, I am looking for something with Absolute Path.

Example:
xsd:schema
<xsd:import namespace="http://example.bank.skjolber.github.com/v1" schemaLocation="**BankCustomerService.xsd**" />
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>

Expecting:

```
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://example.bank.skjolber.github.com/v1" schemaLocation="**http://example.bank.skjolber.github.com/v1/BankCustomerService.xsd**" />
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are not finding the schema or failing the schema validation against you xml data?  Schemas have required data and data that must meet requirements.  You are probably failing the validation test,  Try a google search for "online xml validator" and check you xml.

Comment: My schema validation passes, used some online XML validators. There is no issues with the code, its an issue with the application. To make sure, i need to do an test with external data.

Comment: Does the XML data meet the schema?